# How to make RIA ignore a property when generating entities?

Tags: c#, silverlight, properties, ria

**Background:** Silverlight 4 (*"Library" silverlight project*) RIA connected to Entity Framework Model (*Library.Web web application project*).

**Description:**

I have a class:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }

    // I don't need this one in SL4
    public BookInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to compile, RIA generates the following error:

> Entity 'MyCompany.Library.Book' has a property 'Info' with an
>   unsupported type.

**Question:**
I don't need that property in SL4 application so what I want to know is how to prevent the RIA from trying to generate that property when generating the proxy object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }

    // I don't need this one in SL4
    [Exclude]
    public BookInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

Using the Attribute [Exclude] ria wont pass that property to the client side and it will only be visible on the server side i think this is what you are looking for :D

Answer (score -2):

My error occurred because I needed a default constructor for my property.  In your case it maybe that you need a default constructor for BookInfo